# Ansible playbook target patterns

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I would like to ask you if it is possible to filter the inventory file, using patterns related to variables inside the inventory itself.
For example:

I have this inventory

```
groupA:
  hosts:
   host1A:
     env: pre
   host2A:
     env: prod
groupB:
  hosts:
    host1B:
      env: pre
    host2B:
      env: prod
```

and this is the plabook:

```
- name: test
  hosts: **only hosts that contain env:pre??**
  role: backend
```

Is it possible to achieve that? Maybe using a REG expression?
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are over-riding the `env` value of `host1B`.  Fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

Given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
groupA:
  hosts:
    host1A:
      env: pre
    host1B:
      env: prod
groupB:
  hosts:
    host1B:
      env: pre
    host1C:
      env: prod
```

The simplest option is using module [*group_by*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/group_by_module.html#ansible-builtin-group-by-module-create-ansible-groups-based-on-facts). For example,

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - group_by:
        key: group_{{ env }}
    - debug:
        var: groups
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [group_by] *******************************************************************************
changed: [host1A]
changed: [host1B]
changed: [host1C]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [host1A] => 
  groups:
    all:
    - host1A
    - host1B
    - host1C
    groupA:
    - host1A
    - host1B
    groupB:
    - host1B
    - host1C
    group_pre:
    - host1A
    - host1B
    group_prod:
    - host1C
    ungrouped: []

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
host1A: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host1B: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host1C: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

This is probably not what you want. The host *host1B* is not a member of the *prod* group because the variable *env* evaluates to *'pre'*.

You can easily fix it by putting all options into a comma-separated list. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
groupA:
  hosts:
    host1A:
      env: pre
    host1B:
      env: prod,pre
groupB:
  hosts:
    host1B:
    host1C:
      env: prod
```

and the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - group_by:
        key: "group_{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ env.split(',') }}"
    - debug:
        var: groups
      run_once: true
```

gives what you want

```yaml
PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [group_by] *******************************************************************************
ok: [host1A] => (item=pre)
ok: [host1B] => (item=prod)
ok: [host1C] => (item=prod)
ok: [host1B] => (item=pre)

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [host1A] => 
  groups:
    all:
    - host1A
    - host1B
    - host1C
    groupA:
    - host1A
    - host1B
    groupB:
    - host1B
    - host1C
    group_pre:
    - host1A
    - host1B
    group_prod:
    - host1C
    - host1B
    ungrouped: []

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
host1A: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host1B: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host1C: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: i am sorry, there was a problem with the inventory file